# How to break the text in the excel cell using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have two strings , i need to display these two strings in a single excel cell in two lines.Is there any way to break the text into two lines using Apache poi

Comment: @Frank: I tried this, it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* same answer as in the comment, so it can be accepted.

Use `str1 + "\n" + str2`.